# Сразу несколько значений в [ ]

Tags: php

Учусь писать ТГ ботов на php,
такой вопрос у меня ответ на сообщение записан как $DelegateMessage
и каждое последующее слово будет как $DelegateMessage[1]...$DelegateMessage[100]

Как мне сделать так что бы в одном $DelegateMessage[вот тут] было сразу несколько значений
тобишь от 1 до 50, что бы не прописывать все в ручную

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Ну делай так, как и написала

Comment: $DelegateMessage = [0 => 'Message 0', 1 => 'Message 1'];?

Comment: Может `implode($DelegateMessage, ' ')` ?